# ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 60000 input samples and 10000 target samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

> I'm trying to train my Deep Neural Network to recognize handwritten
>   numbers but I keep getting the error stated previously in the title It
>   gives me an error saying: ValueError: Input arrays should have the
>   same number of samples as target arrays. Found 60000 input samples and
>   10000 target samples. How can i fix this? (i already tried
>   train_test_split and transport but nothing worked)

```
# Imports
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import to_categorical

 # Configuration options
 feature_vector_length = 784
 num_classes = 60000

 # Load the data
 (X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

 # Reshape the data - MLPs do not understand such things as '2D'.
 # Reshape to 28 x 28 pixels = 784 features
 X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], feature_vector_length)
 X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], feature_vector_length)

 # Convert into greyscale
 X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
 X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
 X_train /= 255
 X_test /= 255

 # Convert target classes to categorical ones
 Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes)
 Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, num_classes)

 # Load the data
 (X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

 # Visualize one sample
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 plt.imshow(X_train[0], cmap='Greys')
 plt.show()

 # Set the input shape
 input_shape = (feature_vector_length,)
 print(f'Feature shape: {input_shape}')

# Create the model
# Using sigmoid instead of relu function
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(350, input_shape=input_shape, activation="sigmoid", 
kernel_initializer=init))
model.add(Dense(50, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=init))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation="sigmoid", 
kernel_initializer=init))

# Configure the model and start training
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=250, verbose=1, 
validation_split=0.2)

# Test the model after training
test_results = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=1)
print(f'Test results - Loss: {test_results[0]} - Accuracy: 
{test_results[1]}%')
```

Comment: I'd recommend that first you spend some time to clean up your code. Some sections are repeated. Try to debug it too. Are the shapes what you expect? Final note: there's a ton of tutorials on keras with mnist. Have a look at them.

Comment: In addition to the above said, please update your question with the full error trace - as is, it is impossible to say even where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: In any case, you cannot have `num_classes = 60000` !

Comment: ok i think the code is cleaner. Actually i tried to change the num_classes to 1000 but it remains with the error

Comment: Why do you think you have `1000` classes? Have you checked what's in the dataset?

Comment: What do you mean "*tried to change the num_classes to 1000*"? The number of classes is not a parameter to play with it - you are using MNIST, which clearly has **10** classes!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution to your problem, here it is:

```
# Imports
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.utils import to_categorical

 # Configuration options
feature_vector_length = 784
num_classes = 10

# Load the data
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# Reshape the data - MLPs do not understand such things as '2D'.
# Reshape to 28 x 28 pixels = 784 features
# X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], feature_vector_length)
# X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], feature_vector_length)

# Convert into greyscale
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

# Convert target classes to categorical ones
Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes)
Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, num_classes)



# Create the model
# Using sigmoid instead of relu function
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(350, input_shape=input_shape, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(50, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"))

# Configure the model and start training
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=250, verbose=1, 
validation_split=0.2)

# Test the model after training
test_results = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=1)
```

But you should really do some research and understand what every line in your code is supposed to do and what every parameter means. For example, the choice of `sigmoid` activation function being wrong, especially in the final layer is the very first thing to understand. That's one of the many things that you should do research about. Then there is:

1. understanding why and when to reshape your data,
2. what is the purpose of flatten layer
3. and most importantly, understand what is `num_classes` and why it is 10 and not 1000 or 60000